# Invalid URL that works in staging server but fails in production

Tags: javascript, url, join

I just spent a whole night figuring out why our production server had a bug that was missed in our staging servers. And this morning, I finally narrowed it down and nailed it to this piece of code:

```
url = [ database.protocol, '//' + database.host, database.port, ].join(':');
url = [ url, database.db ].join('/');
```

Yeah. How on earth could this actually work? Well, in staging it showed:

```
http://:localhost:5984/fo
```

But in master it showed

```
http://:10.x.x.x:5984/fo (x is a number)
```

The former worked, but the latter didn't. This is where my knowledge on URLs fail me. How on earth is the former valid but the latter not?

EDIT:

To be clear, I think both URLs should be invalid, that this is a bug that should be caught in my staging server. I just want to know why the former URL (:localhost) is interpreted as valid but the latter isn't.

Comment: I think the problem is the `:` before `//`, and you can do it with simple string concatenation...

Comment: You may also have firewall / network issues (often more-so in prod than staging) Once you've got the URL correct (i.e. without the extra ':' as Fong-Wan Chau pointed out), I suggest you try connecting to the database using a command line tool (telnet even) to see if the network will let you through.

Comment: Yeah my question was why did the colon : worked with "localhost" but not with an ip address. Granted it is a code problem, but I was just curious as to why it worked with "localhost". :S

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is (almost always) `127.0.0.1`. `127.0.0.1` is very different to `10.x.x.x`.

If the server is listening on `localhost`, only connections coming from the server itself will be received. Therefore even entering the server's IP is not enough to connect to it from the outside.

Make sure the server is listening on its network IP, rather than the loopback.

Comment: I think the question here is why a prefix : (colon) worked with "localhost" (as in, the URL is valid) while not with an IP address. In my knowledge, BOTH should be invalid, but apparently it is not.